# Show both Ns and proportions in two-way frequency table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to create a table for publication that does not conform to 'tidy' output:

```
dummy <- data.frame(categorical_1 = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a"),
                    categorical_2 = c(rep("one", 5), rep("two", 5)),
                    numeric = sample(1:10, 10))

dummy %>%
  count(categorical_1, categorical_2) %>%
  group_by(categorical_1) %>%      
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n))
```

##### Tidyverse Output

```
  categorical_1 categorical_2     n  prop
  <fct>         <fct>         <int> <dbl>
1 a             one               3   0.6
2 a             two               2   0.4
3 b             one               2   0.4
4 b             two               3   0.6
```

##### Desired Output:

```
Category          One       Two
a                 3 (0.6)     2 (0.4)
b                 2 (0.4)     3 (0.6)
```

Perhaps there are other `mutate` steps I can apply to conform the table to my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` after combining `n` and `prop` into one column

```
library(tidyverse)

d2 %>% 
  mutate(v = paste0(n, ' (', prop, ')')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = categorical_1, names_from = categorical_2, values_from = v) %>% 
  rename_at(1, ~'Category')

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   Category [2]
#   Category one     two    
#   <fct>    <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 a        3 (0.6) 2 (0.4)
# 2 b        2 (0.4) 3 (0.6)
```

Initial data from question

```
d2 <- 
  dummy %>%
    count(categorical_1, categorical_2) %>%
    group_by(categorical_1) %>%      
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(janitor)

dummy %>%
  tabyl(categorical_1, categorical_2) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_ns(position = "front")

#>  categorical_1     one     two
#>              a 3 (0.6) 2 (0.4)
#>              b 2 (0.4) 3 (0.6)
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't differ all that significantly from other answers. I wanted to catch a few things that may just come down to preferences:

- `count` drops groups, whereas `summarise` peels the last group off; since you need the first group (`categorical_1`) again in `mutate`, you might call `group_by`, then `summarise`, then calculate your proportions to have a little more control
- I find `glue`-based functions clearer to work with for this sort of string building than calling `paste` with a variety of punctuation or other delimiters
- Your desired output has title-cased column names without numbers, so I cleaned that up in a final `rename_all`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dummy %>%
  group_by(categorical_1, categorical_2) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n),
         display = str_glue("{n} ({prop})")) %>%
  select(-n, -prop) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = categorical_2, values_from = display) %>%
  rename_all(~str_remove(., "_\\d+") %>% str_to_title())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   Categorical [2]
#>   Categorical One     Two    
#>   <fct>       <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 a           3 (0.6) 2 (0.4)
#> 2 b           2 (0.4) 3 (0.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from your pipe there, we can `unite` `n` and `prop` and `spread`, i.e.

```
dummy %>%
     count(categorical_1, categorical_2) %>%
     group_by(categorical_1) %>%
     mutate(prop = prop.table(n))  %>%
     unite(n_prop, n, prop) %>% 
     spread(categorical_2, n_prop)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
> # Groups:   categorical_1 [2]
>   categorical_1 one   two  
>   <fct>         <chr> <chr>
> 1 a             3_0.6 2_0.4
> 2 b             2_0.4 3_0.6
> ```

You can play around with the delimiter of `unite` and mutate to paste the closed parenthesis If you need it strictly like that

Comment: Replace the `unite` line with   `mutate(prop = paste0("(", prop, ")")) %>%
  unite(n_prop, n, prop, sep = " ")`
`

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(dummy)[, .(count = .N), 
                     .(categorical_1, categorical_2)], 
      categorical_1~categorical_2)[,
                                   .(categorical_1 = categorical_1,
                                     one=paste0(one, " (", one/sum(one), ")"),
                                     two=paste0(two, " (", one/sum(two), ")"))]

#>    categorical_1     one     two
#> 1:             a 3 (0.6) 2 (0.6)
#> 2:             b 2 (0.4) 3 (0.4)
```

***Data:***

```
dummy <- data.frame(categorical_1 = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a"),
                    categorical_2 = c(rep("one", 5), rep("two", 5)),
                    numeric = sample(1:10, 10))
```